# Hung up of fedora installation due maybe to intel backlight

Tags: fedora, system-installation

I was trying to install Fedora 23 KDE onto an Asus X453MA notebook alongside Windows 8.1 then suddenly hung up while in the progress of:

Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight...

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

The sign that the installation hung up is when the cursor stops blinking either visible or not. I always press the power button when it stopped to try another Fedora installation attempt. I tried installing the following:
-Fedora 23 GNOME
-Fedora 22 KDE & GNOME
-Fedora 21 KDE & GNOME
-Fedora 20 KDE
...but they all hung up as well.

The notebook is newly bought and I really need to install Fedora 23 KDE now because I'm developing a software coded in Java and PL/SQL. I tried replacing Windows 8.1 and then installing Windows 7 but unsuccessful due to UEFI BIOS non-compliant of ACPI showed in the blue screen. I presumed that the non-compliant issue is not the problem because I did install a current version of Ubuntu wiping the OEM Windows 8.1.

The questions are:
1. What might are the problems keeping me from installing Fedora 23 KDE?
2. Is the problem the Intel video card or any hardware?
3. Am I still be able to install and use Fedora, or will I need to use another laptop?
4. Best laptop to use for Linux.